# Returning 'c_str' from a function

Tags: c++, c, c-strings, c-str, static-allocation

This is from a small library that I found online:

```
const char* GetHandStateBrief(const PostFlopState* state)
{
    static std::ostringstream out;

    // ... rest of the function ...

    return out.str().c_str()
}
```

In my code I am doing this:

```
const char *d = GetHandStateBrief(&post);
std::cout<< d << std::endl;
```

Now, at first `d` contained garbage. I then realized that the C string I am getting from the function is destroyed when the function returns because `std::ostringstream` is allocated on the stack. So I added:

```
return strdup( out.str().c_str());
```

And now I can get the text I need from the function.

I have two questions:

1. Am I understanding this correctly?
2. I later noticed that `out` (of type `std::ostringstream`) was allocated with static storage. Doesn't that mean that the object is supposed to stay in memory until the program terminates? And if so, then why can't the string be accessed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

strdup allocates a copy of the string on the heap, which you have to free manually later (with `free()` I think). If you have the option, it would be much better to return `std::string`.

The static storage of `out` doesn't help, because `.str()` returns a temporary `std::string`, which is destroyed when the function exits.

Answer (score 3):

You're right that `out` is a static variable allocated on the data segment.  But `out.str()` is a temporary allocated on the stack.  So when you do `return out.str().c_str()` you're returning a pointer to a stack temporary's internal data.  Note that even if a string is not a stack variable, `c_str` is "only granted to remain unchanged until the next call to a non-constant member function of the string object."

I think you've hit on a reasonable workaround, assuming you can't just return a string.

Comment: Hmm, "static variable allocated on the heap" - never heard of such thing :)

Comment: Well, the character data of the string is indeed stored on the heap with any std::string, whether static or whatever.  It's the string descriptor stored on the data segment like other variables with global lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

strdup() returns a char* pointer that is pointing to memory on the heap. You need to free() it when you're done with it, but yes, that will work.

The static local variable `std::ostringstream out` makes no sense in this case, unless the std::string being returned was also static which your observation is showing to be not true.

Answer (score -1):

In `GetHandStateBrief`, variable `out` does not need to be static.  You need an explicit `static string` to replace the temporary that was being created in your original call to `out.str()`:

```
static std::string outStr;
std::ostringstream out;
... rest of function ...
outStr = out.str();
return outStr.c_str();
```

Comment: This is risky. The returned `char*` isn't guaranteed to be valid after a subsequent call to `GetHandStateBrief`.

Comment: True that every call to `GetHandStateBrief` will invalidate the pointer returned by the previous call.  The risk is context dependent though.

Comment: No downvote from me either, but the 'static variable in the function so we can return a pointer instead of just returning the object' is a a bit of a well-known antipattern in C++. See Scott Meyer's Effective C++ 2nd edition, Item 23.

Comment: I don't think this is no worse that the original code (except this one works). strdup in a C++ program isn't necessarily any better.

Comment: All true - but I'll leave it as this succeeds at what he was trying to do.   I've had to use a similar anti-pattern across dlls when the CRT is not shared.  OTOH, I agree that this should not be practiced if the object can be returned instead.